# What's the best way to transfer data to another XAML page?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

The documented way to navigate to another XAML page while passing in data seems to be by serializing the data as URL parameters.  This works great for simple parameters, such as a single database key:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewContact.xaml?contactid=" + cid, UriKind.Relative));
```

However, what if you want to pass in a rather complicated data structure, such as a search query?  This query might have keywords, various filters, arrays of items, etc.  It would be rather difficult to express this sort of data using URL parameters.

**Question: What is the recommended technique to navigate to another page, passing in non-trivial parameters?**

One idea would be to first set the data or query as a static property of the page you've navigating to:

```
Query q = new Query();
// Set various parameters
ViewContact.SearchQuery = q;
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewContact.xaml?contactid=", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then, when ViewContact was loaded, it would check that static property and load the data into memory.

Anything wrong with this approach, or is there another method that's recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this thread on the Prism discussion board: [Navigation using Object as parameter](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/248576).

Near the end, there is a solution using a `NavigationUri` class derived from `Uri`:

```
public sealed class NavigationUri : Uri
{
  public NavigationUri(string uri)
    : base(uri, UriKind.Relative)
  {
    Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  }

  public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters
  {
    get;
    private set;
  }
}
```

(I made the constructor public)

You can then use it like so:

```
var uri = new NavigationUri("/ViewContact.xaml");
uri.Parameters["SearchQuery"] = q;
NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
```

Then, in the `OnNavigatedTo` method of your `ViewContact`:

```
public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
  var uri = (NavigationUri)navigationContext.Uri;
  SearchQuery = (Query) uri.Parameters["SearchQuery"];
}
```

As suggested in the original thread, you can also use a class to generate the parameter keys instead of hardcoding them:

```
public sealed class NavigationUriParameters
{
    public static readonly string SearchQuery = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is interesting - I'd be careful to test when the app gets tombstoned and comes back if the Parameters are restored as well as the Uri.

Comment: Yes. I usually use both mechanisms: this one if the data I need is already loaded into memory (e.g. in View which is navigated from) and the raw Uri parameters as a fallback if the data is not yet loaded.

Comment: `+1` for this idea..  But yea, seems a bit hacky and I'm have to test to make sure it works with the back/forward stack.

Answer (score 1):

In my apps I've passed some sort of identifier in the URL parameter, like

```
/FlightInfo.xaml?FlightID=4
```

and then look up that flight ID in the `OnNavigatedTo()` method.  The flights are stored in the ViewModel which I keep as a static property somewhere, so it's similar but this way your URL's are meaningful and back/resume will work better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for Silverlight and want to support deep linking you will have to put all the information that is needed to load the data and display the page in the URL because the url is what is stored in the link.

In all other cases (Silverlight without deep linking or Windows Phone) you could store (part of) the information elsewhere in some globally available object such as the App.

As mentioned you can pass an identifier of the object and retrieve the object when loading the page (get it from a service or a cache)

You could also store the current ViewModel/Data in the App object and simply bind it to the new page.

Depending on the amount of resources (time, bandwidth, concurrent users, ...) available, you might want to pick one of these or even switch between solution depending on the scenario.

Comment: The scenario I'm talking about is if there isn't a simple identifier for an object to retrieve.  In this case, I'm trying to pass in search criteria which cannot be expressed easily through URL parameters.  I think just doing the search asynchronously and storing that on the App object is the correct approach here.